# Open default camera in android?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera

I have searched a lot but i did not get any solution. I want to open default camera of my android device so that i can capture image as well as video. I have tired it using:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(intent, ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
```

or

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(intent, ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
```

But using this camera open only in one mode either in Image or in Video capture mode. I want to open default camera. **Please don't suggest using Surface View holder.**

Thanks a lot in Advacnce

Comment: is it **tired** or **tried** man ?? please correct it.

Comment: I dont think Android allows to do so..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Please don't suggest using Surface View holder.
```

You `can't` do it.Both in `one time`.Either you open image or video.You should put alert for choose one Video or image.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Samir but that i know, it is the last option :)

Comment: ya its las t option but can create Without surfaceview

Answer (score 0):

You will have to get native interaction for that purpose. Search for Qualcomm's Augmented Reality Sample apps. In that they have opened the Camera natively and not through Android's Camera api.