# Camera.open() returns null

Tags: android, android-camera

When I call `mCamera = Camera.open()` it returns null, what could be causing this? My device is the Nexus 7.

I already have the permissions set in my `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

Comment: Try [this](http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/39.html)

Comment: Again, `camera = Camera.open();` returns null.

Comment: Yes...I'm a bit of an idiot though...the API reads `Creates a new Camera object to access the first back-facing camera on the device. If the device does not have a back-facing camera, this returns null.`...the Nexus 7 doesn't have a back facing camera, only a front one.

Comment: Yes. Before, seeing the device i didn't know this. Just know i know this through [the document](http://www.google.com/nexus/#/7) Try to open secondary camera. And, once just try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9765935/940096)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Figured it out,

You need to call `Camera.open(0)`.

THIS IS ONLY VALID AND WORKING ON THE NEXUS 7 device, as it only has one camera, so is only useful if targeting that device only.

Comment: Also read [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#open%28int%29)

Comment: This is wrong answer. First, `0` is a hardcoded number. Second, as @Praveen mentioned, you should use both [getNumberOfCameras()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#getNumberOfCameras()) and [open(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#open(int)).

Comment: @LaiVung did you actually read all the post - I specifically mention that it's only valid for devices with one camera.

Comment: I know. But `0` is a hardcoded value. I'd avoid of using it. You can state my opinion is wrong, it's up to you.

Comment: LaiVung / user1521536 is correct.  Do not hardcode camera id values.  This answer is a broken shortcut that worked for one person in one instance.

Comment: Come on guys, how could a hardcoded value be the right answer to your problems? Start understanding the problems without using these damned shortcuts.

Comment: Using `open(0)` is perfectly legitimate. The [official doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#open%28int%29) says: *`cameraId` `int`: the hardware camera to access, between 0 and [getNumberOfCameras()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#getNumberOfCameras())-1.* So, if the the app manifest **requires** "android.hardware.camera" feature, then cameraId=0 can be used.

Answer (score 5):

For those who's testing an app on Android 6.0+, make sure that you have implemented [Runtime Permission](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html).
Because simple permission in your AndroidManifest file is not enough.

Comment: Can't believe this has lesser upvotes compared to answer. This could just be the solution, worked for me...

Comment: Well, first answer was at the time, when where was no such thing like runtime permissions. Anyway, glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by following below steps.

1. Open the "AVD Manager" and select the virtual device you are using
2. Click on the "Edit" button
   [image: Click on edit button]
3. In the "Hardware" section, select "New" and add "Configures camera facing back" and click Ok.
4. In the dropdown next to the entry, select "webcam0" or the one corresponding to the camera you want to use
   [image: Select the camera you want to use]
5. Stop the AVD and restart again.

Answer (score 0):

If you build app above API 22, maybe you should request permission.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) Try to elaborate more to make your answer clearer and include more details.