# Android custom Camera app

Tags: android, android-camera, surfaceholder

Trying to develop android Camera App with custom preview layout for recording videos.
Folowing this source:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html
Camera's preview works fine,
but the problem begins when I try to record video.
After pressing the capture button the App crashes.

During debugging I figured out that problem occurs during the creating of Camera instance. Camera.open() doesn't work (what means that camera is not available) and I receive Camera object = null (getCameraInstance() method returns null).

I tried to specify which camera to open as advised here
[Camera.open() returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12054022/camera-open-returns-null)
But it doesn't help.

Also the app crashes after pausing and resuming it (I think the problem is also in onPause() / onResume().

Wery appreciate any piece of advice

My code is here:

Activity:

```
package com.leo.leoscamera;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.media.CamcorderProfile;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

public class CameraActivity extends Activity {

    private Camera mCamera;
    private CameraPreview mPreview;
    private MediaRecorder mMediaRecorder;
    private static final int MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO = 2;
    private static final String TAG = "L-Camera";
    private boolean isRecording = false;
    Button captureButton;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // Create an instance of Camera
        mCamera = getCameraInstance();

        // Create our Preview view and set it as the content of our activity.
        mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);
        FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
        preview.addView(mPreview);


        // Add a listener to the Capture button 
        captureButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_capture);
        captureButton.setOnClickListener( 
            new View.OnClickListener() { 
                @Override 
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (isRecording) {
                        // stop recording and release camera 
                        mMediaRecorder.stop();  // stop the recording 
                        releaseMediaRecorder(); // release the MediaRecorder object 
                        mCamera.lock();         // take camera access back from MediaRecorder 


                        // inform the user that recording has stopped 
                        captureButton.setText("Capture");
                        isRecording = false;
                    } else { 
                        // initialize video camera 
                        if (prepareVideoRecorder()) { 
                            // Camera is available and unlocked, MediaRecorder is prepared, 
                            // now you can start recording 
                            mMediaRecorder.start(); 

                            // inform the user that recording has started 
                            captureButton.setText("Stop");
                            isRecording = true;
                        } else { 
                            // prepare didn't work, release the camera 
                            releaseMediaRecorder(); 
                            // inform user 
                        } 
                    } 
                } 
            } 
        ); 
    }


/**
 * Configuring the MediaRecorder
 * @return
 */

    private boolean prepareVideoRecorder(){ 

        mCamera = getCameraInstance(); 
        mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

        // Step 1: Unlock and set camera to MediaRecorder 
        mCamera.unlock(); 
        mMediaRecorder.setCamera(mCamera); 

        // Step 2: Set sources 
        mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);

        // Step 3: Set a CamcorderProfile (requires API Level 8 or higher) 
        mMediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));

        // Step 4: Set output file 
        mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO).toString()); 

        // Step 5: Set the preview output 
        mMediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(mPreview.getHolder().getSurface()); 

        // Step 6: Prepare configured MediaRecorder 
        try { 
            mMediaRecorder.prepare(); 
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "IllegalStateException preparing MediaRecorder: " + e.getMessage());
            releaseMediaRecorder(); 
            return false; 
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "IOException preparing MediaRecorder: " + e.getMessage());
            releaseMediaRecorder(); 
            return false; 
        } 
        return true; 
    } 


    /** A safe way to get an instance of the Camera object. */
    public static Camera getCameraInstance() {
        Camera c = null;
        try {
            c = Camera.open(); // attempt to get a Camera instance
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
            Log.d(TAG, "Camera is not available");
        }
        return c; // returns null if camera is unavailable
    }

    /** Check if this device has a camera */
    private boolean checkCameraHardware(Context context) {
        if (context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(
                PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
            // this device has a camera
            return true;
        } else {
            // no camera on this device
            return false;
        }
    }


    /** Create a file Uri for saving an image or video */ 
    private static Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type){
          return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
    } 

    /** Create a File for saving an image or video */ 
    private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type){
        // To be safe, you should check that the SDCard is mounted 
        // using Environment.getExternalStorageState() before doing this. 

        File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                  Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "MyCameraApp");
        // This location works best if you want the created images to be shared 
        // between applications and persist after your app has been uninstalled. 

        // Create the storage directory if it does not exist 
        if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){
            if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
                Log.d("MyCameraApp", "failed to create directory");
                return null; 
            } 
        } 

        // Create a media file name (only video files)
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        File mediaFile;
        if(type == MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
            "VID_"+ timeStamp + ".mp4");
        } else { 
            return null; 
        } 

        return mediaFile;
    } 

     @Override 
        protected void onPause() { 
            super.onPause(); 
            releaseMediaRecorder();       // if you are using MediaRecorder, release it first 
            releaseCamera();              // release the camera immediately on pause event 
        } 

      @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();  
            if(mCamera == null){
            mCamera = getCameraInstance();

            mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);
            FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
            preview.addView(mPreview);
            }
        }    
        private void releaseMediaRecorder(){ 
            if (mMediaRecorder != null) {
                mMediaRecorder.reset();   // clear recorder configuration
                mMediaRecorder.release(); // release the recorder object
                mMediaRecorder = null;
                mCamera.lock();           // lock camera for later use 
            } 
        } 

        private void releaseCamera(){ 
            if (mCamera != null){ 
                mCamera.release();        // release the camera for other applications 
                mCamera = null; 
            } 
        } 
}
```

Preview:

```
  package com.leo.leoscamera;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.List;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.hardware.Camera;
    import android.hardware.Camera.Size;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
    import android.view.SurfaceView;
    import android.view.View;

    /** A basic Camera preview class */ 
    public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
        private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
        private Camera mCamera; 
        private static final String TAG = "Preview";

        public CameraPreview(Context context, Camera camera) {
            super(context);
            mCamera = camera; 

            // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the 
            // underlying surface is created and destroyed. 
            mHolder = getHolder();
            mHolder.addCallback(this);
            // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0 
            mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
        } 

        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            // The Surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw the preview. 
            try { 
                mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
                mCamera.startPreview(); 
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
            } 
        } 

        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            // empty. Take care of releasing the Camera preview in your activity. 
        } 

        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
            // If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events here. 
            // Make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it. 

            if (mHolder.getSurface() == null){
              // preview surface does not exist 
              return; 
            } 

            // stop preview before making changes 
            try { 
                mCamera.stopPreview(); 
            } catch (Exception e){
              // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview 
            } 

            // set preview size and make any resize, rotate or 
            // reformatting changes here 

            // start preview with new settings 
            try { 
                mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
                mCamera.startPreview(); 

            } catch (Exception e){
                Log.d(TAG, "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
            } 
        }    
}
```

Manifest:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android:hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        <activity
            android:name=".CameraActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

Logcat:

```
07-23 22:22:51.715: W/ActivityThread(17225): Application com.leo.leoscamera is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
07-23 22:22:51.717: I/System.out(17225): Sending WAIT chunk
07-23 22:22:51.735: I/dalvikvm(17225): Debugger is active
07-23 22:22:51.918: I/System.out(17225): Debugger has connected
07-23 22:22:51.919: I/System.out(17225): waiting for debugger to settle...
07-23 22:22:52.119: I/System.out(17225): waiting for debugger to settle...
07-23 22:22:52.320: I/System.out(17225): waiting for debugger to settle...
07-23 22:22:52.520: I/System.out(17225): waiting for debugger to settle...
07-23 22:22:52.721: I/System.out(17225): waiting for debugger to settle...
07-23 22:22:52.921: I/System.out(17225): waiting for debugger to settle...
07-23 22:22:53.122: I/System.out(17225): waiting for debugger to settle...
07-23 22:22:53.323: I/System.out(17225): waiting for debugger to settle...
07-23 22:22:53.523: I/System.out(17225): waiting for debugger to settle...
07-23 22:22:53.724: I/System.out(17225): waiting for debugger to settle...
07-23 22:22:53.924: I/System.out(17225): waiting for debugger to settle...
07-23 22:22:54.125: I/System.out(17225): waiting for debugger to settle...
07-23 22:22:54.326: I/System.out(17225): waiting for debugger to settle...
07-23 22:22:54.526: I/System.out(17225): waiting for debugger to settle...
07-23 22:22:54.727: I/System.out(17225): waiting for debugger to settle...
07-23 22:22:54.928: I/System.out(17225): waiting for debugger to settle...
07-23 22:22:55.129: I/System.out(17225): waiting for debugger to settle...
07-23 22:22:55.330: I/System.out(17225): waiting for debugger to settle...
07-23 22:22:55.530: I/System.out(17225): waiting for debugger to settle...
07-23 22:22:55.731: I/System.out(17225): waiting for debugger to settle...
07-23 22:22:55.932: I/System.out(17225): waiting for debugger to settle...
07-23 22:22:56.133: I/System.out(17225): waiting for debugger to settle...
07-23 22:22:56.334: I/System.out(17225): waiting for debugger to settle...
07-23 22:22:56.535: I/System.out(17225): waiting for debugger to settle...
07-23 22:22:56.735: I/System.out(17225): waiting for debugger to settle...
07-23 22:22:56.940: I/System.out(17225): debugger has settled (1448)
07-23 22:23:02.545: I/SurfaceView(17225): updateWindow -- onWindowVisibilityChanged, visibility = 0
07-23 22:23:02.615: E/(17225): appName=com.leo.leoscamera, acAppName=/system/bin/surfaceflinger
07-23 22:23:02.615: E/(17225): 0
07-23 22:23:02.621: I/MaliEGL(17225): [Mali]window_type=1, is_framebuffer=0, errnum = 0
07-23 22:23:02.622: I/MaliEGL(17225): [Mali]surface->num_buffers=4, surface->num_frames=3, win_min_undequeued=1
07-23 22:23:02.622: I/MaliEGL(17225): [Mali]max_allowed_dequeued_buffers=3
07-23 22:23:02.674: I/[MALI][Gralloc](17225): dlopen libsec_mem.so fail
07-23 22:23:02.683: I/SurfaceView(17225): updateWindow -- setFrame
07-23 22:23:02.689: I/SurfaceView(17225): updateWindow -- OnPreDrawListener, mHaveFrame = true
07-23 22:23:02.692: I/SurfaceView(17225): Changes: creating=true format=true size=true visible=true left=true top=true mUpdateWindowNeeded=false mReportDrawNeeded=false redrawNeeded=false forceSizeChanged=true mVisible=false mRequestedVisible=true
07-23 22:23:02.699: I/SurfaceView(17225): Cur surface: Surface(name=null)/@0x424b3588
07-23 22:23:02.727: I/SurfaceView(17225): New surface: Surface(name=null)/@0x424b3658, vis=true, frame=Rect(0, 0 - 866, 540)
07-23 22:23:02.728: I/SurfaceView(17225): Callback --> surfaceCreated
07-23 22:23:02.729: I/SurfaceView(17225): surfaceCreated callback +
07-23 22:23:03.318: I/SurfaceView(17225): surfaceCreated callback -
07-23 22:23:03.320: I/SurfaceView(17225): surfaceChanged -- format=4 w=866 h=540
07-23 22:23:03.320: I/SurfaceView(17225): surfaceChanged callback +
07-23 22:23:04.670: I/SurfaceView(17225): surfaceChanged callback -
07-23 22:23:04.670: I/SurfaceView(17225): surfaceRedrawNeeded
07-23 22:23:04.670: I/SurfaceView(17225): finishedDrawing
07-23 22:23:04.683: I/Choreographer(17225): Skipped 136 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-23 22:23:04.700: I/SurfaceView(17225): updateWindow -- OnPreDrawListener, mHaveFrame = true
07-23 22:23:04.706: I/SurfaceView(17225): Changes: creating=false format=false size=false visible=false left=false top=false mUpdateWindowNeeded=true mReportDrawNeeded=true redrawNeeded=false forceSizeChanged=false mVisible=true mRequestedVisible=true
07-23 22:23:04.709: I/SurfaceView(17225): Cur surface: Surface(name=null)/@0x424b3588
07-23 22:23:04.729: I/SurfaceView(17225): New surface: Surface(name=null)/@0x424b3658, vis=true, frame=Rect(0, 0 - 866, 540)
07-23 22:23:04.730: I/SurfaceView(17225): surfaceRedrawNeeded
07-23 22:23:04.731: I/SurfaceView(17225): finishedDrawing
07-23 22:23:04.871: I/SurfaceView(17225): updateWindow -- UPDATE_WINDOW_MSG
07-23 22:23:04.915: I/SurfaceView(17225): updateWindow -- setFrame
07-23 22:23:04.919: I/SurfaceView(17225): updateWindow -- OnPreDrawListener, mHaveFrame = true
07-23 22:23:07.744: I/View(17225): Touch down dispatch to android.widget.Button{424a2650 VFED..C. ........ 866,234-960,306 #7f090040 app:id/button_capture}, event = MotionEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, id[0]=0, x[0]=20.077026, y[0]=9.548996, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=191289023, downTime=191289023, deviceId=3, source=0x1002 }
07-23 22:23:07.776: I/View(17225): Touch up dispatch to android.widget.Button{424a2650 VFED..C. ...P..ID 866,234-960,306 #7f090040 app:id/button_capture}, event = MotionEvent { action=ACTION_UP, id[0]=0, x[0]=21.075989, y[0]=9.548996, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=191289100, downTime=191289023, deviceId=3, source=0x1002 }
07-23 22:23:07.800: I/SurfaceView(17225): updateWindow -- OnPreDrawListener, mHaveFrame = true
07-23 22:23:09.951: W/CameraBase(17225): An error occurred while connecting to camera: 0
07-23 22:23:13.078: W/dalvikvm(17225): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41e25cf8)
07-23 22:23:13.078: W/dalvikvm(17225): threadid=1: uncaught exception occurred
07-23 22:23:13.088: W/System.err(17225): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-23 22:23:13.092: W/System.err(17225):    at com.leo.leoscamera.CameraActivity.prepareVideoRecorder(CameraActivity.java:95)
07-23 22:23:13.095: W/System.err(17225):    at com.leo.leoscamera.CameraActivity.access$5(CameraActivity.java:89)
07-23 22:23:13.097: W/System.err(17225):    at com.leo.leoscamera.CameraActivity$1.onClick(CameraActivity.java:64)
07-23 22:23:13.100: W/System.err(17225):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4463)
07-23 22:23:13.102: W/System.err(17225):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18770)
07-23 22:23:13.105: W/System.err(17225):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
07-23 22:23:13.118: W/System.err(17225):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
07-23 22:23:13.120: W/System.err(17225):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
07-23 22:23:13.123: W/System.err(17225):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5333)
07-23 22:23:13.125: W/System.err(17225):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-23 22:23:13.128: W/System.err(17225):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-23 22:23:13.130: W/System.err(17225):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
07-23 22:23:13.132: W/System.err(17225):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
07-23 22:23:13.134: W/System.err(17225):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-23 22:23:13.135: W/dalvikvm(17225): threadid=1: calling UncaughtExceptionHandler
07-23 22:23:13.183: E/AndroidRuntime(17225): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-23 22:23:13.183: E/AndroidRuntime(17225): Process: com.leo.leoscamera, PID: 17225
07-23 22:23:13.183: E/AndroidRuntime(17225): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-23 22:23:13.183: E/AndroidRuntime(17225):    at com.leo.leoscamera.CameraActivity.prepareVideoRecorder(CameraActivity.java:95)
07-23 22:23:13.183: E/AndroidRuntime(17225):    at com.leo.leoscamera.CameraActivity.access$5(CameraActivity.java:89)
07-23 22:23:13.183: E/AndroidRuntime(17225):    at com.leo.leoscamera.CameraActivity$1.onClick(CameraActivity.java:64)
07-23 22:23:13.183: E/AndroidRuntime(17225):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4463)
07-23 22:23:13.183: E/AndroidRuntime(17225):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18770)
07-23 22:23:13.183: E/AndroidRuntime(17225):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
07-23 22:23:13.183: E/AndroidRuntime(17225):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
07-23 22:23:13.183: E/AndroidRuntime(17225):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
07-23 22:23:13.183: E/AndroidRuntime(17225):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5333)
07-23 22:23:13.183: E/AndroidRuntime(17225):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-23 22:23:13.183: E/AndroidRuntime(17225):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-23 22:23:13.183: E/AndroidRuntime(17225):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
07-23 22:23:13.183: E/AndroidRuntime(17225):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
07-23 22:23:13.183: E/AndroidRuntime(17225):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-23 22:23:17.512: I/Process(17225): Sending signal. PID: 17225 SIG: 9
```

Comment: You should add the crash report from the log to the question so we can see where and why it's failing.

Comment: added logcat. . I think that camera is still in use by preview